# When is the frobenius of a set of numbers smaller than their sum?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to know if there's any result on when is the frobenius of a set of numbers $g(a_1,\cdots,a_n)$ smaller than $a_1+\cdots+a_n$. For instance; $g(7,11,17,19)=27<54=7+11+17+19$. I'm particularly interested on $n\geq3$ as $n=2$ is better understood. I have the feeling most of the time this will be true but I don't know how to prove it and honestly it feels out of my reach.

I've also stumbled upon [this](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ecis511/Frobenius-number.pdf) paper in which they state results by Selmer (1977) and Lewin (1972) which seem useful. Although I don't really understand Selmer's one as if $p_1<k$ then you get nonsense.

If someone knows a result related to this or can help me using the results above it would be of much help

Comment: I don't think there is going to be a good characterization unless you add extra conditions.

Comment: @Yorch Yeah, I figured, I know it's likely to be a research difficult problem, just wanted to know if there are any useful partial results

Comment: If you allow coefficients to be 0, then it's the lowest  of any pair at most.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee What if there's no two of them that are coprime (This can still happen even if the three of them are corpime, for instance, (6,10,15))

Comment: My point is if a subset can fill in all numbers above a point below your sum, so can the whole set. In your example change 19 out for 29 and you can still guarantee it,because the sum increased by 10 the lower bound from the first 2, got exceeded by the sum ( in fact any number greater than 24 can make that true) .  The lowest for 2 non coprimes doesn't exist. But, you can say they will fill in every multiplier of their gcd from the value obtained from their coprime parts ...

Comment: If you limit the set so it does not contain 1) any number greater than $g(a,b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are the coprime pair in the set with the smallest product and 2) no number that is linear combination of any others. Then I think you will find that $p_1/k \ge 1$. Excluding such numbers does not change the Frobenius number of the set.